# Corrupted SD Card - RPi does not boot

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, ubuntu

I am new in Ubuntu, Raspberry Pi and PanStamp. So, I found a “tutorial” to help me understand how can I work with them. I found this:

```
https://code.google.com/p/panstamp/wiki/RaspberryPi
```

The steps seem easy.

1. Download the latest image
   here:www.panstamp.org/lagarto_imag...pi_0.8_2gb.zip
2. Unzip and write the image to the SD card (at least 2 GB) according to the Raspberry Pi Wiki: For Windows, use Win32 Disk
   Imager For Linux, use dd if=lagarto_rpi_xyz.img of=/dev/sdc
3. Insert the SD card in your Raspberry Pi and boot it up.
4. By default, Raspbian comes with with DHCP enabled so you need to get the IP-address from your DHCP server.
5. Once started, you should be able to access: ip-address:8001 for Lagarto-SWAP ip-address:8002 for Lagarto-MAX
6. You can SSH to the Raspberry and login using username "pi" and password "raspberry"

My first target is to write the Lagarto Server into the SD Card. My SD Card has already Raspbian and has 3 partitions. The 3 partitions are:

1. file system FAT32, with size 1,43GB (SETTINGS)
2. file system FAT32, with size 60MB (BOOT)
3. file system ext4, with size 5,68GB (root)

So I try to write the image in the 3rd partition, because Lagarto demands 2GB. The 3rd partition was /dev/sdb6. I edit the command above, as: if=lagarto_rpi_xyz.img of=/dev/sdb6
I waited enough time but no error was showed. So, I supposed that the procedure was fine.

Then, I put out the SD card from the laptop and carefully, I put it in the Raspberry Pi B+.
But, it shows me problem.
“ No filesystem could mount root, tried: ext4”
“kernet panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root FS on unknown -block (179,6)”

So, I turn off the Raspberry and I put the SD card again to the laptop.
I run Gparted and I noticed that “/dev/sdb6” has problem.
“File system is damaged”, “file system is unknown to Gparted”, “The device entry /dev/sdb6 is missing”.

Obviously, I have stuck in Step 2.
What should I do now, so I can continue my work?
How can I un-done the command “if=lagarto...” or I repair the “damaged” partition?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you over thought this. You should *not* pick a partition to write the image to - rather you should write it to the *card*. If /dev/sdb6 is a partition, then /dev/sdb represents the card. You need to unmount all the partitions of the card before you can write image to the card.

Good luck.

Comment: So, I have to: 1.Unmount the SD Card, 2. Flash the SD Card. 3. Write the img of Lagarto(with the Raspbian) in SD. correctly?

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose. But writing the image to the card is what is usually referred to as "flashing".

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding! When i write it wrong. Like step 2,  i mean format the SD Card. So, so I dont have no partitions. Do you know a programe to do this, i.e. the whole format of SD card?

Comment: Ah, ok. No. You don't need to format the card. Just write to it, it should do.

Comment: With NOOBS I managed to re-install Raspbian. 
Now, if i write again "dd if=lagarto_rpi_0.8_2gb.img of=/dev/sdc" but this time to write the img to SD and not to a partition, it will work? Or i have to install all the parts of Lagarto (pyserial, ZeroMQ with the Python bindings and Barrel), so to be sure?

Comment: Why do you want to install noobs? Is sdc the path to the card?

Comment: The NOOBS was istalled in SD card when they give it to me. Yes the path to the card is "/dev/sdc". I kept a (correct) img ofthe SD card with Raspbian. Then i wrote the img with the "dd" command in the SD card ("/dev/sdc") but now the Raspberry does not boot. Just black screen.. What may was wrong again?

Comment: I brought back the correct image of the SD. And I try to install Lagarto step by step by this link https://github.com/panStamp/panstamp/wiki/lagarto#installation. I did the procedure twice, but it did not work. I can find where is the server files and i cannot run the servers.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue of SD-CARD corruption. if you turn off power, when you write something to SD card it will cause SD-Card corruption. So make sure you don't turn off when you write to your SD-Card (by proving UPS etc., or Don't write to file system).

Another potential cause might be power supply. I was using POE to power my pi, and I had frequent problems such as Pi going offline, etc., After changing the power supply the problem is gone.

Still I have crash problem (rarely though) with pi's which are powered through USB. I strongly suggest using recommended power supply.

Comment: I can't stress enough how important is to have a good power supply and not to turn off the RPi without a `shutdown now` and wait for a few blinks (red green and the stop).
Most cheap SD cards. (and some not so cheap but old) are easily damaged with sudden lost of power.